# trying to filter in controller does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, filter, entity-framework-core

I've created a model by scaffolding my database and then created the controller by entity framework core

Then I am trying to make a filter on `FullName` field in `Index` method in the controller like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var nozContext = _context.NzAll.Include(n => n.CodeKNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeKhNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeMrNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeSexNavigation).Include(n => n.HalaNavigation);
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
    var nzAllIQ = from s in _context.NzAll
                         select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
       nzAllIQ = nzAllIQ.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(await nozContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Then I put this form in index.cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="index" method="get">
   <div class="form-actions no-color">
      <p>
        Search by Name
        <input type="text" name="searchString" value= "@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
       </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I press submit button no filtering is done!

Why? and how to solve please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your return value is not fiiltered data **nzAllIQ**.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string searchString)
    {
        var nozContext = _context.NzAll.Include(n => n.CodeKNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeKhNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeMrNavigation).Include(n => n.CodeSexNavigation).Include(n => n.HalaNavigation);           
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        var nzAllIQ = from s in nozContext
                      select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            nzAllIQ = nzAllIQ.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(await nzAllIQ.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TextSearch(string searchName)
        {
            var result = db.Jobs.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchName)
            || a.JobContent.Contains(searchName)
            || a.Category.CategoryName.Contains(searchName)
            || a.Category.CategoryDescription.Contains(searchName)).ToList();

            return View(result);
        }
```

Can you try this or

```
public ActionResult Search(string CategoryId, string sehir)
        {


            var nur = sehir;

            var category = db.Jobs.Where(b => b.Sehir == sehir).ToList();


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CategoryId.ToString()) == true && string.IsNullOrEmpty(nur) == true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }




            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CategoryId.ToString()) == true)
            { category = db.Jobs.Where(b => b.Sehir == sehir).ToList(); return View(category.OrderByDescending(x => x.Tarih).ToList()); }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nur) == true)
            { category = db.Jobs.Where(b => b.CategoryId.ToString() == CategoryId).ToList(); return View(category.OrderByDescending(x => x.Tarih).ToList()); }



            else
            {
                category = db.Jobs.Where(b => b.Sehir == sehir && b.CategoryId.ToString() == CategoryId).ToList();
                return View(category.OrderByDescending(x => x.Tarih).ToList());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hey, I might be wrong but I'm failing to see how this code helps the OP asking the question? This seems like a totally different code.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the filter to a different `IQueryable` variable. You do `nzAllIQ.Where...` but you return `nozContext.ToListAsync()`. `nozContext` has no way of knowing about your intent to filter. This probably fix it without changing your code too much.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var nozContext = _context.NzAll
    .Include(n => n.CodeKNavigation)
    .Include(n => n.CodeKhNavigation)
    .Include(n => n.CodeMrNavigation)
    .Include(n => n.CodeSexNavigation)
    .Include(n => n.HalaNavigation);    
    
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        nozContext = nozContext.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(await nozContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Without prolonging myself, I have a few tips for you. Try not to return your EF Entities from your controller. Usually, DTO's or ViewModels (just normal classes) are used instead, where you project only the fields necessary for your view. This way you save on database calls not having to return a lot of fields you won't be using.